# Django REST Framework Server Error On Heroku

Tags: heroku, django-rest-framework, internal-server-error

I deployed my DRF (Django REST Framework) on Heroku recently. The error is when I try to send POST request to API. The POST method sends username and password to the given endpoint. The endpoint is `https://api-ads-ebike.herokuapp.com/users/register/`. Here is the following error :
[image: Error On Heroku]

But when I try it on Postman and run the project locally, I found no error as follows :
[image: Success]

Here is the `settings.py` file :

```
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["api-ads-ebike.herokuapp.com"]

APPEND_SLASH = False

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'drf_spectacular',
    'api.apps.ApiConfig',
]
```

`models.py` file :

```
from django.db import models

    # Create your models here.
    class User(models.Model):
        user_id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
        username = models.CharField(max_length=256)
        password = models.CharField(max_length=16)
        date_created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    
        def __repr__(self):
            return str(self.user_id)
```

`views.py` file :

```
from rest_framework import generics, permissions
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer
from .serializers import UserSerializer, StationSerializer, CycleSerializer
from .models import User, Station, Cycle
from api import serializers
import datetime
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
# import jwt
# Create your views here.

@api_view(['GET'])
def get_user(requets):
    user = User.objects.all()
    serializer = UserSerializer(user, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

@api_view(['GET'])
def get_user_by_id(request, pk):
    user = User.objects.get(user_id=pk)
    serializer = UserSerializer(user, many=False)
    return Response(serializer.data)

@api_view(['POST'])
def register(request):
    serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
    password = make_password(request.data['password'])
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save(password=password)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

`url.py` file :

from django.urls import path, register_converter
from . import views

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("users/", views.get_user),
    path("users/<int:pk>", views.get_user_by_id),
    path("users/register/", views.register)]
```

Procfile :

```
web: gunicorn ads_api.wsgi
```

I also already ran `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` on Heroku.

Thank you very much for your response

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: [HTTP 500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error) is a generic server-side error message. On its own it doesn't tell us anything useful. Any time you see this your first step should be to check your _server-side_ error logs for more detail. On Heroku, start by running `heroku logs`.

Comment: @Chris the problem has been solved by change the function based view to class based view using APIView class